# How to handle basic HTML authentication without Flask or Django

Tags: python, html, sql, python-3.x, authentication

I want the user to fill in his credentials on my HTML page, let Python query the credentials and, if correct, forward to the next page. If the credentials are wrong, then redirect to a different page.

I've managed to authenticate the user with hard-coded credentials but when the user clicks on "log in" the user gets forwarded to an HTML page that I've put in my Python script. I did this because i don't know how to forward or redirect when authenticated.

I've been searching Google and looking through the documentation but all I get are scraper questions!

My specs: Apache, MariaDB, WSGI, Python3, HTML5.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337246/redirect-a-user-to-url-with-wsgi-no-framework

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed. How can i mark the above as correct answer?